# selenium-4 - How to use HasVirtualAuthentication with Remote driver to pass userName and password in authentication popup

Tags: basic-authentication, remotewebdriver, selenium4

We need the way to handle authentication popup with RemoteWebDriver.

In webDriver we have below option to handle this ..

webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

((HasAuthentication) webDriver).register(UsernameAndPassword.of("admin", "admin"));

We need similar implementation for RemoteWebDriver. But we dont have hasAuthentication for remoteWevDriver instead we have HasVirtualAuthenticator.

Can someone suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try sending the credentials using:
protocol://username:password@domain

e.g. https://admin:admin@jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/Basic/